# @angular/elements how can I update my custom element at the end of a rest call?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-elements

So I have this easy component:

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-element',
  template: '<div>{{ chuckText$ | async }}</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})

export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  public chuckText$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  public constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  this.chuckText$.next('Default Text');
}

  ngOnInit() {
    // nothing too fancy, just for testing purpose
    this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data.value);
        this.chuckText$.next(data.value);
      });
  }
}
```

After building my component and adding it in a simple angularJS app, (I need to add a custom element to an old app) I get my element with the default text and the http.get result in the console, but my component has not been updated, as shown in the picture.

[image: Like this]

I'm clearly missing something that is just not obvious to me. Any idea on why the content does not update?
As a reminder this feature is released but in an experimental state, maybe it's just that.

For reference this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button/button.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  entryComponents: [ButtonComponent],
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const customElement = createCustomElement(ButtonComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('custom-button', customElement);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() { }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the same problem with some of mine custome elements. Somehowe the `change detection` acts differently in a custome element than in a regular angular application and doesn't update the view accordingly.

**Solution 1**

If you are updating the state of your component invoke the `changeDetection` manually.

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your component's constructor and call `markForCheck()` or `detectChanges()` everytime you like to update your view.

Be aware of `detectChanges()`. It will start the changeDetection process and can have performance issues when you are not use it wisely.

[Docs: ChangeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

**Solution 2**

Inject `NgZone` in the component and call `NgZone.run()`.

For example:

`this.ngZone.run(() => this.chuckText$.next(data.value))`

[Docs: NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

Comment: Do we have an explanation for that ? I use Angular materials components and they don't animate properly due to problem in change detection on focus for example. Changedetection work but the UI is not smooth

Comment: Solution 2 worked better in my case as solution 1 breaks other stuff like Material animations.